# Database Relationship Direct vs Indirect Reference of Foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have 3 tables in a MySql DB named Users, Deals and Sales. Now Users table has one to many relationship with Deals table and Deals table has one to many relationship with Sales table.

Now I didn't setup any direct one to many relationship between Users and Sales (But they are already indirectly referenced via foreign keys deal_id(Sales)-> user_id(Deals)->User. So If I want to search sales by a User, I can easily run a join query and get Sales by user_id.

I also can create a direct one to many relationship between User and Sale by putting user_id foreign key in Sales table.

Now from good practice and/or performance point of view which approach is better?

Comment: So every deal consists of several sales and all those sales (for the same deal) belong to the same user?

Comment: Yeah one deal belong to the just one user (as I've stated they have one to many relationships)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what the relationships actually are.  If `sales` really depends on `deals`, then you can look up the user from there.  This would be true if `sales` were really a subtype of `deals`, for instance.  Or, if the user changed for some reason on the `deal`, would it change automatically for the corresponding `sale`?

However, if `sales` is an independent entity and has a relationship with `users`, then you'll want to include the column in `sales.  This would be particularly true if a sale were comprised of many deals, but I think your data model goes the other way.

From what you say, looking up the value through a join sounds very reasonable.  This will affect performance, but with the right indexing, the queries should be fine.

Comment: Can you explain what did you mean by "Or, if the user changed for some reason on the deal"

Comment: @Econ_newbie . . . If you updated the user on a deal, how would that affect the sale?

Comment: If I update any column in user, the primary key of user is still the same. So nothing changes there as the foreign key references are still intact. But if I remove the user, all children i. e. Deals and sales are also deleted

Comment: Additionally I don't change user in deals table as a particular deal will always belong to the same user. But let's say I change a deal and put another user in it, the deal is s

Comment: . But let's say I change a deal and put another user in it, the deal id is still the same which is referenced as foreign key of sales table. So in this case sales of this deal are still linked to the changed user